# Custom Connector - OData Queries - Make them pretty?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to write a custom connector Swagger file for Logic Apps and am having problems. The API I want to connect to only accepts OData queries so all my parameters are asking for $filter and the user has to type in Name eq 'Name' and Id eq 1. Is there a way to make this prettier and just ask them for the parameters directly?

I tried just adding them in (Name, Id, Active) but it puts them in the url like ?Name=.  Not in the OData syntax. Is there any way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The custom connectors are designed to work as interfaces to existing REST APIs and the UI is more of a 1-1 mapping of their specification.

AFAIK, there is no way to direct customize how the connectors work but you could achieve it by proxy request through your own service.

You simply need a service which accepts requests the way you want and translate them accordingly for the actual service.

[Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) is probably the best candidate for this. As a bonus, once you have the APIs you need designed, you get an OpenAPI spec that you could use for the custom connector.
Depending on your expected load, you might have to use its [Consumption Tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-api-management-for-serverless-architectures/) but do note that its currently in preview.

The alternatives could be having your own [API hosted on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api) or [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) instead (or even [Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies)), again depending on your expected load.

**PS:** The downside of doing this is the obvious maintenance that you would have to uptake in case your requirements change and/or the backend API changes.